# Thread safe array

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, thread-safety

Im awful at multithreadding but ever since I added the following line to my application it seems to crash quite often so Im assuming its not thread safe.

private readonly string[] _foo = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();

What are my options to make this thread safe?

Comment: There's nothing right or wrong with that line of code. You need to show us how you're using the foo array, that's likely where the issue is.

Comment: Sorry for such limited information, I will try to get you guys some more when I have some time.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that initializes the array is fine. You're marking the array as `readonly`, which means that it is not possible to assign a new array to the `_foo` field - but your code can still modify elements of the array. The operation itself will not cause crash, but if the array is changed from multiple threads, you may get unexpected results.

Without more information, it is difficult to say what the problem is. In what ways does your application crash?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# 4 you can use some already built-in collections. They are faster than any blocking collection as they rely on lock free strategies.

Take a look at the [Concurrent Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

- `List<T>` or `T[]` --> `SynchronizedCollection<T>` (be aware that enumeration is not thread-safe)
- `Dictionary<T>` --> `ConcurrentDictionary<T>`
- `Queue<T>` --> `ConcurrentQueue<T>`
- `Stack<T>` --> `ConcurrentStack<T>`
- also consider `BlockingCollection<T>` for Producer-Consumer scenarios